# Sorting a List<String> containg coordinates x and y

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting, split

Can anyone please help me sort the following List of Strings:

The List<**String**> contains coordinates

[0] "0 0"
[1] "0 1"
[2] "0 2"
[3] "0 3"
[4] "1 1"
[5] "1 2"
[6] "1 3"

Although It may not always be in that order I would like to make sure it is, by sorting / ordering it (sort by X coordinate ASC then by Y coordinate ASC)

I have tried this but it does not alter the list at all? - see below

`boardObjectList.OrderBy(p => (p.Split())[0]).ThenBy(p=> (p.Split())[1]);`

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
JP

Comment: Why not turn the coordinate strings into a class or struct (e.g. `struct IntPoint { int X; int Y; }`) first, and storing that list.  Then ordering as you wish becomes `boardObjectList.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(p => p.Y);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OrderBy` and `ThenBy` do not modify the original list, they only return a new list (in the form of an `IEnumerable<>`). What you need to do is create a new `List<>` from the resulting `IEnumerable<>`, like this:

```
// Note that we are assigning the variable to a new list
boardObjectList = boardObjectList.OrderBy(p => (p.Split())[0])
                                 .ThenBy(p => (p.Split())[1])
                                 .ToList(); // Also note that we call ToList,
                                            // to get a List from an IEnumerable
```

You will get strange results when storing numbers in strings, and trying to sort. I recommend changing your code to this:

```
boardObjectList = boardObjectList.OrderBy(p => int.Parse(p.Split()[0]))
                                 .ThenBy(p => int.Parse(p.Split()[1]))
                                 .ToList();
```

This method converts the strings into integers before sorting. The reason to do this is that string sorting sorts alphabetically, leading to sorting like this:

```
1
10
11
12
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution. I use a separate struct for the integer coordinate and translate the split string into instances of that.

```
// Defined elsewhere
struct Coord
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}


// Where you're doing your work...
var intCoords = new List<Coord>();
foreach (var coord in boardObjectList)
{
    var str = coord.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
    intCoords.Add(new Coord() { 
        x = Int32.Parse(str[0]), 
        y = Int32.Parse(str[1])
    });
}

// Do the actual sort. Ensure you assign the result to a variable
var newCoords = intCoords.OrderBy(x => x.x).ThenBy(x => x.y).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it won't alter the list at all - LINQ does not modify underyling collections, it simply creates queries.

What you are after is storing the query result in a new list:

```
boardObjectList = boardObjectList.OrderBy(p => (p.Split())[0]).ThenBy(p=> (p.Split())[1]).ToList();
```

EDIT: had another look. You should not compare strings like that - what will happen if any of those "numbers" will be larger than "9"? Here's the updated solution:

```
boardObjectList = boardObjectList.Select(p => new { P = p, Split = p.Split() } ).
    OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split[0])).ThenBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split[1])).
    Select(x => x.P).ToList();
```

EDIT2: You can also do it without LINQ with less memory overhead:

```
boardObjectList.Sort((a, b) =>
    {
        // split a and b
        var aSplit = a.Split();
        var bSplit = b.Split();
        // see if there's a difference in first coordinate
        int diff = int.Parse(aSplit[0]) - int.Parse(bSplit[0]);
        if (diff == 0)
        {
            // if there isn't, return difference in the second
            return int.Parse(aSplit[1]) - int.Parse(bSplit[1]);
        }
        // positive if a.x>b.x, negative if a.x<b.x - exactly what sort expects
        return diff;
    });
```

Comment: May I ask why you create that temporary object with `Select`?

Comment: I was trying to avoid splitting string twice.